# How to record current X and Y co-ordinates of a Component (like a Button) into a Variable in a JFrameForm in Netbeans

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, netbeans-8

Well the question I have is exactly what the topic says .. I simply want to record the X and Y co-ordinates of a component like a JTextField or a Jbutton into variables in a JFrameForm in Netbeans. I searched all around the internet for an answer .. there wasn't one.. maybe this is Impossible if so please tell me so.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi! If you want to save data about relational posiotion, you should use layout with absolute coordinates (sorry don't remember what about JFrameForm, but you should check it). And, of course, it's possible to store additional data to your elements, just create your own childs from this classes with any variables you want to use.

Comment: You should be able to call #getBounds on any object which extends JComponent. From there, you get a Rectangle. Getting x/y values is as simple as rect.x and rect.y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes my friend, it's possible and it's simple.
Assume you want to get the location of a `jButton` the all you have to do is.

```
Point p = jButton.getLocation();
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: thank you very much.. this actually works when you want to get location in relative to objects parent. you could also get the location in terms of X and Y by using `jButton1.getAlignmentX()` and `jButton1.getAlignmentX()` I did this in a null layout though.